# post-install configure installtion falied wps express 8.5

Tags: express, installation, portal, wps

I have downloaded Portal Express v8 installation trail version from IBM and wen i start installing this using Installation manager 'IBM Websphere Application Server Network Deployment v8' got installed successfully but it failed when installing 'IBM Websphere Portal Express v8'. I tried 3/4 times the same happened every time. I have attached required screenshots and error log file. Please help me in resolving this issue.
[image: Screenshot attached]

Answer (score 0):

My "localadmin" account was added in both admin group and user group. Removing the "localadmin" from user group worked for me.